# Configuration beans are not initialized

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I don’t quite understand how this can be, but methods marked as @Bean are not initialized when I run them through the `WebApplicationInitializer`. In the debugger, you can only get to the `@Autowired` setters inside the `@Configuration` classes, but I don't see the initialization of the beans. When I start Spring context with `Junit`, it works fine.

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

WebServiceDispatcherServletInitializer

```
public class WebServiceDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String SERVICE_DISPATCHER_SERVLET = "service_dispatcher_servlet";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebServiceConfig.class, RootConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new CXFServlet());
        dispatcher.addMapping("/services/*");
    }
}
```

**UPD:** PersistenceConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.softcomputer")
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-postgres.properties"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    @Profile("postgres")
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.connection_url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.username")));
        dataSource.setPassword(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.password")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("postgres")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean postgresSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(postgresDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"com.softcomputer", "com.softcomputer.testdomain"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(postgresAdditionalProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties postgresAdditionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.hbm2ddl.auto")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.dialect")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.show_sql")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.default_schema")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.globally_quoted_identifiers")));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

**UPD1:** Beans in `WebServiceConfig.class` are not initialized either. But `RootConfig.class` is initialized fine (all config classes has `@Configuration` annotation)

**UPD2:** Maybes WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup expect another configuration, as **szatkus** said. Then what kind of startup should be used to run `new CXFServlet()` with such Configuration classes?

Comment: It's looking for a `SessionFactory`. I'm not seeing where you have a `SessionFactory` `@Bean`.

Comment: I have LocalSessionFactoryBean in PersistenceConfig.class.

Comment: The error indicates otherwise. And since we cannot see the problematic code we can't really help.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update post in a second.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalSessionFactoryBean` doesn't implement `SessionFactory` interface. Maybe try:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean) {
    return bean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: I added this bean and it's still not getting run and throws "No qualifying bean of type ...LocalSessionFactoryBean". Maybe something wrong with Spring initialization? Because Junit without any issues invokes configurations via SpringClassRule and SpringMethodRule. Or with SpringRunner